# other languages in flash music player

Tags: html, flash

i am using this code for playing music for my website way2enjoy.com .it playes all songs nicely whose source is in english language but when the source file is in other language say for example arabic it wont play. i have checked the source code using firebug it was 100% corrrect for one flash player and in other flash player it was showing arabic character as ??????????

here is my existing source code .you can see the third div which is arabic. first two will play nicely in the below link but third will not play however everything is just right.

live example    http://way2enjoy.com/try/musictest/drplayer/index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="drplayer.css" type="text/css" />

<script src="jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="drplayer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#playlist").playlist(
            {
                playerurl: "swf/drplayer.swf"
            }
        );
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="playlist">
    <div href="29.mp3" style="width: 400px;" class="item">
        <div>
            <div class="fr duration"></div>
            <div class="btn play"></div>
            <div class="title"><b></b> - Shut up and let me </div>
        </div>
        <div class="player inactive"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div href="30.mp3" style="width: 400px;" class="item">
        <div>
            <div class="fr duration"></div>
            <div class="btn play"></div>
            <div class="title"><b>Metallica</b> - Nothing else matters</div>
        </div>
        <div class="player inactive"></div>
    </div>

   <div class="clear"></div>
    <div href="ارجعلي.mp3" style="width: 400px;" class="item">
        <div>
            <div class="fr duration"></div>
            <div class="btn play"></div>
            <div class="title"><b>Arabic song</b> - Arabic song</div>
        </div>
        <div class="player inactive"></div>
    </div>

</div>




<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="$('#playlist').playlist('prev');">Prev</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="$('#playlist').playlist('next');">Next</a>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="$('#playlist').playlist('pause');">Pause</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="$('#playlist').playlist('play');">Play</a>
```

here is link for other player i tried

http://way2enjoy.com/music/viewstory/3406

Comment: `ارجعلي.mp3` is not a valid URL, that may well be your problem. If that is true, you will have to URL encode it or use a latin-only URL. Unicode support is still shaky here

Comment: @Pekka how i can convert all languages character into english character so if i have something in arabic ,chinese it get converted into english language so that it can be read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ارجعلي.mp3` is not a valid URL, that may well be your problem. If that is true, you will have to URL encode it or use a latin-only URL.

Here is an on-line URL encoder:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

it turns the file name into

```
%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AC%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%8A.mp3
```

which should be displayed okay in most browsers (ie. as `ارجعلي.mp3`), and always work.

Comment: how i can generate that dynamically so that i will give the source as %D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AC%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%8A.mp3

Comment: @user what programming language are you using?